# Why mouse align to grid is flickering?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a board where i calculate everything with millimeters and at drawout i calculate back to pixels.

I also have a mouse position in pixels, and a grid, where i want to align my mouse.

Functions calculate between pixels and millimeters:

```
int global::mmToPixel(double value)
{
    return global::dpi / (double)25.4 * value;
}

double global::pixelToMm(int value)
{
    return  ((double)value) / (global::dpi / (double)25.4);
}
```

My values:

```
global::dpi = 600.0;
global::gridSize = 2.54;
```

And the mouse position function:

```
QPointD canvas::mousePosition(bool tiled)
{
   QPoint mp = this->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos());

   mp.setX(mp.x() - mp.x()%global::mmToPixel(global::gridSize));
   mp.setY(mp.y() - mp.y()%global::mmToPixel(global::gridSize));

   QPointD p(global::pixelToMm(mp.x()), global::pixelToMm(mp.y()));
   return p;
}
```

Dpi is the dots/inch. gridSize is how big a tile is. mp is contain the mouse coordinates and p is the aligned coordinates.

I tried a lot of versions(calculating with pixels or millimeters) but either of those worked. Sometimes when the mouse is on the edge of the tile it's flickering, and jump 1 or to tiles in a direction(random where).

If i remove the 2 aligner lines it's works perfectly. When i wrote it in c# it worked, but in c++ doesn't now.

QPoint contains 2 int and QPointD is a custom class it contains 2 double value;

Any ideas?
Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Why is this tagged `math`?

Comment: I did think it's kind of related there, but i removed it. :) Sorry if it did bother you.

Comment: Since i asked the question realized it jumping only 1 tile.

Comment: I found the answer, it was the moving function somewhere else. I can't find where i can remove the question.